# AngularJS $scope variable on window onclick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a button which when clicked displays a windows and hides it when the button is clicked again.I want the window to close even if any other place in the page is clicked.

This is my code :

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle multiselect-btn" ng-click="content=!content;contentClick=true">

//The div to show hide
<div ng-class="{'open':content}" > div content </div>
```

I wrote the following window on click code in the controller but it didn't work..

```
$window.onclick = function () {
    if($scope.contentClick){
    $scope.contentClick=0;  
    }
    else{$scope.content=false;
    $scope.$apply();}

    }
```

What is the correct way to do this?Can anyone please guide me in the right direction.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change your controller ID:

```
window.onclick = function () {
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('controller_id')).scope();
            if(scope.contentClick){
                scope.contentClick=0;  
            }
            else{
               scope.content=false;
               scope.$apply();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve after content was clicked, but you can `$watch` `content value` in controller and run some action when content change value

Please see script below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.$watch('content', function(value) {

    if (value) {

      $scope.contentClick = 1;
    } else {
      $scope.contentClick = 0;
    }


  })

});
```

```css
.open {
  color: red ;opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">

    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle multiselect-btn" ng-click="content=!content;contentClick=true">Click me </a>
    <hr/>//The div to show hide
    <div ng-class="{'open':content}">div content {{contentClick}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```